# Why does this while loop not work as intended in C

Tags: c, file, while-loop, copy

Im trying to write a program which copies the contents of a file and then puts the contents in another file. My Code works but just copies one character. I think my `while` loop is wrong and I do not know how to fix it. Can you help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Check if the user provided exactly two filenames
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s [source_file] [destination_file]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;  // Return an error code to indicate failure
    }

    // Open the source file for reading
    FILE *source = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

    if (source == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Unable to open the source file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open the destination file for writing
    FILE *destination = fopen(argv[2], "wb");

    if (destination == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Unable to open the destination file.\n");
        fclose(source); // Close the source file before exiting
        return 1;
    }

    char buffer[1024];
    size_t bytes_read;

    // Copy the contents of the source file to the destination file
    while ((bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), source)) > 0) {
        fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes_read, destination);
    }

    // Close both files
    fclose(source);
    fclose(destination);

    printf("File copied successfully.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think there's something else than your program that is wrong. Your program makes a perfect copy  for me. Check the return value from the `fwrite` and `fclose`s too. Perhaps it writes "short" for some reason.

Comment: Have you **saved** this version before recompiling? You could be executing a previous version of the source that was not correct..

Comment: That was it thanks a lot !!!

Comment: No worries. Happens to everyone now that these modern IDE's are allowing every career taxi driver and busboy to write code...

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in the code posted. The program should copy the file whose name is specified as the first argument to a new file with the name specified as the second argument, which will be created or truncated if it already exists.  The only caveat is if the program is run with the same file as source and destination: the file will be truncated before its contents can be read, resulting in data loss.

The problem is elsewhere...

There is no portable way to tell if `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` name the same file if they are different strings, but some other improvements can be implemented, such as more explicit error messages:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int status = 0;

    // Check if the user provided exactly two filenames
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s [source_file] [destination_file]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;  // Return an error code to indicate failure
    }

    // Open the source file for reading
    FILE *source = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (source == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to open the source file %s: %\n",
                argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    // Open the destination file for writing
    FILE *destination = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
    if (destination == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to open the destination file %s: %s\n",
                argv[2], strerror(errno));
        fclose(source); // Close the source file before exiting
        return 1;
    }

    char buffer[BUFSIZ > 1024 ? BUFSIZ : 1024];
    size_t bytes_read;

    // Copy the contents of the source file to the destination file
    while ((bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), source)) > 0) {
        size_t bytes_written = fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes_read, destination);
        if (bytes_written != bytes_read) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: cannot write %zu bytes\n",
                    bytes_read - bytes_written);
            status = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Close both files
    fclose(source);
    if (fclose(destination)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: closing file %s failed: %s\n",
                argv[2], strerror(errno));
        status = 1;
    }

    if (!status) {
        printf("File copied successfully.\n");
    }
    return status;
}
```

Comment: @Fe2O3: using `BUSIZ` *might* indeed optimise the throughput, but the C Standard makes no such guarantee.  It only specifies that *the value of the macro `BUFSIZ` shall be at least `256`* and `BUFSIZ`, defined in `<stdio.h>` *expands to an integer constant expression that is the size of the buffer used by the `setbuf` function.*  Using a buffer size at least as large as the one set by `fopen()` is definitely a good idea, and assuming that `fopen` uses a buffer with a length of `BUFSIZ` is not wrong albeit not certain. Answer amended.

Comment: you can `stat` the two files and they will be the same, in case they have the same `st_dev` and `st_ino`.   And this is portable enough along POSIX systems, IMHO.  This is how tools like `tar(1)` or `cpio(1)` check to avoid duplicating files or to remake the links to the same file on restoring a backup.

Comment: @LuisColorado: yes this method is classic on POSIX systems, but it does not work on Windows or other systems. Hence my phrase *There is no portable way...*

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit strange that you do a full check of errors in all your preliminary functions, but just imagine that all the routines called in the loop work corrrectly.

```
    char buffer[1024];
    size_t bytes_read;

    // Copy the contents of the source file to the destination file
    while ((bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), source)) > 0) {
        fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes_read, destination);
    }
```

you should consider the possibility of `fread` returning `< 0` (which is an error, this can happen sometimes, if you read from a socket, or a device)  and check the result code of `fwrite`.  A better approach could be:

```
    // Copy the contents of the source file to the destination file
    while ((bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), source)) > 0) {
        ssize_t written = fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes_read, destination);
        if (written < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "fwrite error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
        if (written < bytes_read) {
            fprintf(stderr, "partial write\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    if (bytes_read < 0) {
         fprintf(stderr, "fread error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
         exit(1);
    }
```

although you are using `fread` and `fwrite` calls double buffering the input/output, so it would be simpler to use a one byte buffer:

```
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(source)) != EOF) {
        if ((c = fputc(c, destination)) == EOF)
            break;
    }
    if (ferror(source)) {
        // error on reading source
    }
    if (ferror(destination)) {
        // error on writing destination
    }
```

that will use the best buffer size (stdio gets normally the best buffer size based on the filesystem's optimum buffering) and you will not have to guess it.